# Round to nearest second

Tags: excel, time, formula, rounding, milliseconds

I am not that comfortable with Excel, yet trying to do something that is quite simple.
I have a cell which contains date + timestamp, such as : 2022-05-21 23:59:55.961
However, I'd like to round it and have : 2022-05-21 23:59:56.
(On the contrary, I'd like to round 2022-05-21 23:49:55.161 down to 2022-05-21 23:49:55, for instance). The idea is to get rid of the milliseconds and round the values accordingly.
Do you know of any function that could help me do that ? It is a bit tricker because I have the timestamp in the same cell and the round function I have gives me "#VALUE?", because it does not understand the time, yet I need to keep it.

Thank you in advance for your help,
Regards

Comment: Possibly using MROUND, but if you're getting "#VALUE!" with ROUND, you probably have text-that-looks-like-a-date.

Comment: Indeed, I returned the type of the cell and it treats it as a string... any idea how I could proceed ?

Comment: In testing, `MROUND` still worked with a datestring, so use something like. `=MROUND(A1, 1/86400)`.

Comment: In my case, it still returns "#VALUE!" with MROUND

Comment: May need to `TRIM` and/or `CLEAN` the value first, and you can also try coercing to a number with `--`.